# CSS media queries are selectively not working

Tags: html, css, user-interface, sass, media-queries

Thank you in advance.

I'm working on the mobile responsiveness of a challenge project and my media queries are only selectively working. Here is my full HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Frontend Mentor | Sunnyside agency landing page</title>
</head>

<body>

  <section class="splash_page">
    <header>
      <nav class="navbar">
        <img src="./images/logo.svg" class="sunnyside_logo" alt="sunnyside_logo">
        <ul class="nav_links">
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="contact_button">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="intro_screen">
      <h2>We are creatives</h2>
      <img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" />
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="grid_card">
    <div class="card_information">
      <div class="transform_information_container">
        <h2>Transform your brand</h2>
        <p>We are a full-service creative agency specializing in helping brands grow fast.
          Engage your clients through compelling visuals that do most of the marketing for you.</p>
        <a>Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card_image">
      <img src="./images/desktop/image-transform.jpg" />
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="grid_card_2">
    <div class="card_information">
      <div class="stand_out_information_container">
        <h2>Stand out to the right audience</h2>
        <p> Using a collaborative formula of designers, researchers, photographers, videographers, and copywriters,
          we’ll build and extend your brand in digital places.
        </p>
        <a>Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card_image">
      <img src="./images/desktop/image-stand-out.jpg" />
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="grid_card_3">
    <div class="card_image">
      <div class="graphic_design_text">
        <h2> Graphic Design</h2>
        <p>Great design makes you memorable. We deliver artwork that underscores your brand message and captures
          potential clients’ attention.
        </p>
      </div>
      <img src="./images/desktop/image-graphic-design.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="card_image">
      <div class="photography_text">
        <h2>Photography</h2>
        <p>Increase your credibility by getting the most stunning, high-quality photos that improve your business image.
        </p>
      </div>
      <img src="./images/desktop/image-photography.jpg" />
    </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="testimonials">
    <h2>Client Testimonials</h2>
    <div class="testimonial_group">
      <div class="single_testimonial">
        <img src="images/image-emily.jpg" />
        <p> We put our trust in Sunnyside and they delivered, making sure our needs were met and deadlines were always
          hit.
        </p>
        <h3 class="testimonial_name">
          Emily R.
        </h3>
        <small>Marketing Director</small>
      </div>
      <div class="single_testimonial">
        <img src="images/image-thomas.jpg" />
        <p> Sunnyside’s enthusiasm coupled with their keen interest in our brand’s success made it a satisfying and
          enjoyable experience.
        </p>
        <h3 class="testimonial_name">
          Thomas S.
        </h3>
        <small>Chief Operating Officer</small>
      </div>
      <div class="single_testimonial">
        <img src="images/image-jennie.jpg" />
        <p> Incredible end result! Our sales increased over 400% when we worked with Sunnyside. Highly recommended!
        </p>
        <h3 class="testimonial_name">
          Jennie F.
        </h3>
        <small>Business Owner</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="footer">
    <div class="image_banner">
      <img src="./images/desktop/image-gallery-milkbottles.jpg">
      <img src="./images/desktop/image-gallery-orange.jpg">
      <img src="./images/desktop/image-gallery-cone.jpg">
      <img src="./images/desktop/image-gallery-sugarcubes.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="banner_information">
      <img src="./images/logo-footer.svg" class="logo_footer"/>
      <div class="footer_nav">
        <p>About</p>
        <p>Services</p>
        <p>Projects</p>
      </div>
      <div class="footer_links">
        <svg class="facebook_logo" width="20" height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M18.896 0H1.104C.494 0 0 .494 0 1.104v17.793C0 19.506.494 20 1.104 20h9.58v-7.745H8.076V9.237h2.606V7.01c0-2.583 1.578-3.99 3.883-3.99 1.104 0 2.052.082 2.329.119v2.7h-1.598c-1.254 0-1.496.597-1.496 1.47v1.928h2.989l-.39 3.018h-2.6V20h5.098c.608 0 1.102-.494 1.102-1.104V1.104C20 .494 19.506 0 18.896 0z" fill="#2C7566" fill-rule="nonzero"/></svg>
        <svg class="instagram_logo" width="20" height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M10 1.802c2.67 0 2.987.01 4.042.059 2.71.123 3.975 1.409 4.099 4.099.048 1.054.057 1.37.057 4.04 0 2.672-.01 2.988-.057 4.042-.124 2.687-1.387 3.975-4.1 4.099-1.054.048-1.37.058-4.041.058-2.67 0-2.987-.01-4.04-.058-2.718-.124-3.977-1.416-4.1-4.1-.048-1.054-.058-1.37-.058-4.041 0-2.67.01-2.986.058-4.04.124-2.69 1.387-3.977 4.1-4.1 1.054-.048 1.37-.058 4.04-.058zM10 0C7.284 0 6.944.012 5.877.06 2.246.227.227 2.242.061 5.877.01 6.944 0 7.284 0 10s.012 3.057.06 4.123c.167 3.632 2.182 5.65 5.817 5.817 1.067.048 1.407.06 4.123.06s3.057-.012 4.123-.06c3.629-.167 5.652-2.182 5.816-5.817.05-1.066.061-1.407.061-4.123s-.012-3.056-.06-4.122C19.777 2.249 17.76.228 14.124.06 13.057.01 12.716 0 10 0zm0 4.865a5.135 5.135 0 100 10.27 5.135 5.135 0 000-10.27zm0 8.468a3.333 3.333 0 110-6.666 3.333 3.333 0 010 6.666zm5.338-9.87a1.2 1.2 0 100 2.4 1.2 1.2 0 000-2.4z" fill="#2C7566" fill-rule="nonzero"/></svg>
        <svg class="twitter_logo" width="20" height="17" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M20 2.172a8.192 8.192 0 01-2.357.646 4.11 4.11 0 001.805-2.27 8.22 8.22 0 01-2.606.996A4.096 4.096 0 0013.847.248c-2.65 0-4.596 2.472-3.998 5.037A11.648 11.648 0 011.392 1a4.109 4.109 0 001.27 5.478 4.086 4.086 0 01-1.858-.513c-.045 1.9 1.318 3.679 3.291 4.075a4.113 4.113 0 01-1.853.07 4.106 4.106 0 003.833 2.849A8.25 8.25 0 010 14.658a11.616 11.616 0 006.29 1.843c7.618 0 11.923-6.434 11.663-12.205A8.354 8.354 0 0020 2.172z" fill="#2C7566" fill-rule="nonzero"/></svg>
        <svg class="pinterest_logo" width="20" height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M10 0C4.477 0 0 4.477 0 10c0 4.237 2.636 7.855 6.356 9.312-.088-.791-.167-2.005.035-2.868.181-.78 1.172-4.97 1.172-4.97s-.299-.6-.299-1.486c0-1.39.806-2.428 1.81-2.428.852 0 1.264.64 1.264 1.408 0 .858-.546 2.14-.828 3.33-.236.995.5 1.807 1.48 1.807 1.778 0 3.144-1.874 3.144-4.58 0-2.393-1.72-4.068-4.176-4.068-2.845 0-4.516 2.135-4.516 4.34 0 .859.331 1.781.745 2.281a.3.3 0 01.069.288l-.278 1.133c-.044.183-.145.223-.335.134-1.249-.581-2.03-2.407-2.03-3.874 0-3.154 2.292-6.052 6.608-6.052 3.469 0 6.165 2.473 6.165 5.776 0 3.447-2.173 6.22-5.19 6.22-1.013 0-1.965-.525-2.291-1.148l-.623 2.378c-.226.869-.835 1.958-1.244 2.621.937.29 1.931.446 2.962.446 5.523 0 10-4.477 10-10S15.523 0 10 0z" fill="#2C7566" fill-rule="nonzero"/></svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the entire CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow:wght@600&family=Fraunces:wght@700;900&display=swap');

:root {
    --Soft-red: hsl(7, 99%, 70%);
    --Yellow: hsl(51, 100%, 49%);
    --Dark-desaturated-cyan: hsl(167, 40%, 24%);
    --Dark-blue: hsl(198, 62%, 26%);
    --Dark-moderate-cyan: hsl(168, 34%, 41%);

    --Very-dark-desaturated-blue: hsl(212, 27%, 19%);
    --Very-dark-grayish-blue: hsl(213, 9%, 39%);
    --Dark-grayish-blue: hsl(232, 10%, 55%);
    --Grayish-blue: hsl(210, 4%, 67%);
    --White: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    height: 100vh;
    font-size: 18px;
}

h2, p, h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.splash_page {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;

    background-image: url('./images/desktop/image-header.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    font-family: "Barlow";
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;

    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;

    padding: 2em 3em;
}

.navbar > .nav_links {
    display: flex;

    list-style: none;
    align-items: center;

    justify-content: space-between;

    margin: 0;
    width: 35%;
}

.navbar > .nav_links > li {
    font-size: .90em;
}

.navbar > .nav_links > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.navbar > .sunnyside_logo {
    width: 10em;
}

.navbar > .nav_links > li > .contact_button {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1.25em 2em;

    color: var(--Very-dark-desaturated-blue);
    font-family: "Fraunces";
    font-size: .85em;
    font-weight: 900;

    text-transform: uppercase;

    border-radius: 30px;
}

.navbar > .nav_links > li > .contact_button:hover {
    background-color: hsl(199, 100%, 75%);
    color: white;
    transition: .15s;
}

.intro_screen {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.intro_screen > h2 {
    font-family: "Fraunces";
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 3.5em;

    letter-spacing: .1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    color: white;
    margin: 2em 0 1.65em 0; 
}

.grid_card, .grid_card_2, .grid_card_3 {
    display: flex;
    /* max-height: 75vh; */
}

.grid_card_2 {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.card_information, .card_image {
    flex: 1;
}

.card_information {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

div[class$="information_container"] {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    
    max-width: 22rem;

    text-align: start;
}

div[class$="information_container"] > h2 {
    font-family: "Fraunces";
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 2.5rem;

    color: var(--Very-dark-desaturated-blue);
}

div[class$="information_container"] > p {
    line-height: 1.75em;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: var(--Dark-grayish-blue);

    font-family: "Barlow";

    margin: 2rem 0 2rem 0;
}

div[class$="information_container"] > a {
    font-family: "Fraunces";
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 900;

    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: var(--Very-dark-desaturated-blue);

    position: relative;
    align-self: flex-start;

    padding: 0 .5em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

div[class$="information_container"] > a::after {
    content: '';
    z-index: -1;

    width: 100%;
    height: 0.5rem;
    position: absolute;

    left: 0;
    top: 70%;

    border-radius: 1rem;
    /* background-color: hsl(51, 95%, 83%); */
}

div[class^="transform"] > a::after {
    background-color: hsl(51, 95%, 83%);
}

div[class^="transform"] > a:hover::after {
    background-color: var(--Yellow);

    transition: .15s;
}

div[class^="stand_out"] > a::after {
    background-color: hsl(7, 91%, 91%);
}

div[class^="stand_out"] > a:hover::after {
    background-color: var(--Soft-red);

    transition: .15s;
}

.card_image > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.card_image {
    position: relative;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.graphic_design_text, .photography_text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;

    bottom: 0;

    margin-bottom: 5em;
    width: 22em;
}

div[class$="_text"]  > h2 {
    margin-bottom: .8em;
    font-size: 1.75em;

    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: "Fraunces";
}

div[class$="_text"]  > p {
    font-family: "Barlow";

    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.65em;
}

.graphic_design_text > * {
    color: var(--Dark-desaturated-cyan);
}

.photography_text > * {
    color: var(--Dark-blue);
}

.testimonials {
    /* height: 97vh; */
    margin: 10em 0 10em 0;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.testimonials > h2 {
    margin-bottom: 5em;

    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .4em;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: var(--Dark-grayish-blue);

    font-family: "Fraunces";
}

.testimonial_group {
    display: flex;
    width: 70vw;
}

.single_testimonial {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    padding: 0 .75em 0 .75em;
}

.single_testimonial > img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 3.5em;
}

.single_testimonial > p {
    font-family: "Barlow";
    color: var(--Very-dark-grayish-blue);

    margin: 3em 0 4em 0;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.single_testimonial > .testimonial_name {
    font-family: "Fraunces";
}

.single_testimonial > small {
    font-family: "Barlow";
    color: var(--Grayish-blue);

    margin-top: 1em;
}

.footer {
    /* max-height: 100vh; */

    background-color: hsl(168, 57%, 72%);
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.footer > .image_banner {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;

    width: 100%;
    /* margin: 1em 0 1em 0; */
    /* height: 60vh; */
}

.footer > .image_banner > img {
    width: 100%;
}

.banner_information {
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 40vh; */
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    
    margin: 5em 0 5em 0;
}

.logo_footer {
    align-self: center;
    width: 9em;

    margin-bottom: 2.5em;
}

.footer_nav {
    width: 20em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    font-family: "Barlow";
    color: var(--Dark-moderate-cyan);
}

.banner_information > .footer_nav {
    align-self: center;

    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 5em;
}

.banner_information > .footer_nav > *:hover {
    color: white;

    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .15s;
}

.banner_information > .footer_links {
    align-self: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    width: 9em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.banner_information > .footer_links > svg:hover > path {
    fill: white;

    transition: .15s;
}

@media (max-width: 1440px) {
    .intro_screen > h2 {
        font-size: 3em;
        margin: 2.5em 0 2em 0;
    }

    .graphic_design_text, .photography_text {
        margin-bottom: 3em;
    }

    div[class$="_text"]  > h2 {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
    
    div[class$="_text"]  > p {
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    div[class$="information_container"] {
        max-width: 23em;
    }

    div[class$="information_container"] > h2 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    
    div[class$="information_container"] > p {
        font-size: .9em;
        line-height: 1.5em;
    }
    
    div[class$="information_container"] > a {
        font-size: .9em;
    }

    .testimonial_group {
        width: 85vw;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .navbar > .nav_links {
        width: 55%;
    }
    
    .graphic_design_text, .photography_text {
        margin-bottom: 1.5em;
        width: 20em;
    }

    div[class$="_text"]  > h2 {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
    
    div[class$="_text"]  > p {
        font-size: .9em;
    }

    .testimonials {
        margin: 7em 0 7em 0;
    }

    .testimonials > h2 {
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    .single_testimonial > p {
        font-size: .9em;
        margin: 2em 0 3em 0;
    }
};

@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .intro_screen > h2 {
        color: red;
    }
};

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .grid_card, .grid_card_2, .grid_card_3 {
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }

    .navbar > .nav_links {
        display: none;
    }

    .intro_screen > h2 {
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    .testimonial_group {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
};
```

My problem lies at the end of the CSS code:

```
@media (max-width: 1440px) {
    .intro_screen > h2 {
        font-size: 3em;
        margin: 2.5em 0 2em 0;
    }

    .graphic_design_text, .photography_text {
        margin-bottom: 3em;
    }

    div[class$="_text"]  > h2 {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
    
    div[class$="_text"]  > p {
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    div[class$="information_container"] {
        max-width: 23em;
    }

    div[class$="information_container"] > h2 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    
    div[class$="information_container"] > p {
        font-size: .9em;
        line-height: 1.5em;
    }
    
    div[class$="information_container"] > a {
        font-size: .9em;
    }

    .testimonial_group {
        width: 85vw;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .navbar > .nav_links {
        width: 55%;
    }
    
    .graphic_design_text, .photography_text {
        margin-bottom: 1.5em;
        width: 20em;
    }

    div[class$="_text"]  > h2 {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
    
    div[class$="_text"]  > p {
        font-size: .9em;
    }

    .testimonials {
        margin: 7em 0 7em 0;
    }

    .testimonials > h2 {
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    .single_testimonial > p {
        font-size: .9em;
        margin: 2em 0 3em 0;
    }
};

@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .intro_screen > h2 {
        color: red;
    }
};

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .grid_card, .grid_card_2, .grid_card_3 {
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }

    .navbar > .nav_links {
        display: none;
    }

    .intro_screen > h2 {
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    .testimonial_group {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
};
```

The first two media queries, **max-width: 1440px** and **max-width: 1200px**, function perfectly.

The next two, **max-width: 992px** and **max-width: 600px**, do not function at all. The red color for the *992* entry is for testing purposes.

If I comment the first two entries out—the larger queries that work—the next one will actually function. I've also tried repositioning the media queries, but the same general problem occurs: the top queries will function, while the bottom ones will not.

I think the issue may stem from either my lack of min-height parameters, although I've tried adding those to the existing code and it breaks or tweaks their current function, or my query positioning. All help is much appreciated!

Comment: You've got spurious semi colons in the CSS after the 1200px and 992px and 600px

Comment: you should try to use min-width and max-width in your media queries or even better some framework as bootstrap or Uikit

Comment: Exactly right @AHaworth! I thought I was getting something fundamentally wrong, I just shouldn't have been treating queries like JS functions. Thank you!